# how do 2 low poly animals merge into 1?

Tags: transforms

I am new to Blender and I have created some low poly animals (for example a frog and a bear)

[image]

and I would like to merge them together in order to get a single animal mixing the characteristics of the 2 starting animals.
In this way, I would like to be able to create animals with at one extreme one animal mainly the characteristics of one animal (frog) and a few characteristics of the other animal (bear) and at the other end an animal with a lot of characteristics of the bear and few characteristics of the frog.

[image]

Do you know how to do this?

Thank you very much !

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBvA2Hduk_w, try to look at this quick tutorial from 1:30, it is for older version but it still works same way, You just use shape keys to transfor object from frog to bear and you can stop at 0.2 0.4 0.6 and 0.8 to get those 4 morphing animals (it may not look perfect if your animals are very different, also both animals need same number of vertices)

Comment: Keep in mind, simply interpolating each vertex between two positions (on the right), without considering structure, with no weights, guides etc. is far from ideal (on the left): https://imgur.com/52RlXn2

Comment: BTW, if you create the models from scratch, you can create a basic shape for both animals, create shape keys, then model those animals separately - you can even add new geometry with loopcuts and its will be added for both shape keys in good positions.

Answer (score 4):

You should plan this from the beginning, you can either:

- Duplicate the object to create a second one, model your second object but make sure that you keep the same amount of vertices, then at the end use the *Join as Shape* option in the *Shape Keys* panel in order to save the second shape into the first object (or vice versa), and use the *Value* under the shape keys list in order to transform a shape into the other.
- Or create your object, create a second shape key, keep the second shape key selected and model your second shape, and same thing, use the *Value* under the shape keys list to transform.

Each mesh vertex has an index, to morph from a shape to another Blender must recognize each vertex index. So I'm not sure how you would do it if you have 2 completely different objects.

[image]